# with RIP-addressing, why x86-64 still need relocations?

Tags: assembly, intel, x86-64, elf, relocation

So x86-64 has the RIP-relative addressings which makes PIC codes easy to write and relocations needed much less. Why is relocations still needed then on x86-64? For what features? I can try to explore with `objdump` but what C/C++ code patterns to compile to see?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[This article](http://www.technovelty.org/code/c/amd64-pic.html) explains it better than I can, but basically global variables in a shared library.

Comment: See also the sections concerning relocations in ["How To Write Shared Libraries"](http://www.akkadia.org/drepper/dsohowto.pdf) by Ulrich Drepper.